# Tag merge: bridge and bridging

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I think [bridging](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/bridging) should be merged into [bridge](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/bridge), since it has the same meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Good catch. Merged! And a synonym since it seems a common addition. Especially since the larger tag shows up before the smaller tag when you type 'bri' in the tag line.